# Canoo.net ist jetzt wohl canoonet.eu

Tags: feature-request

Bei Antworten war http://www.canoo.net/ eine Seite, auf die gerne verlinkt wurde. Aber auf http://www.canoonet.eu/ heißt es:

> Bitte beachten Sie, dass diese Seite nur noch über die URL www.canoonet.eu erreichbar ist.

Damit dürften viele Links, die auf canoo.net verweisen, kaputt sein. Ist es möglich, Links in Antworten automatisch umzuschreiben?

**Neuer Stand 2. April 2020**: https://dict.leo.org/pages/about/ende/canoonet_de.html

> ## LEO übernimmt Inhalte von CanooNet
>
> Vielen Sprachbegeisterten ist das Angebot von CanooNet.eu (ehemals canoo.net) sicherlich ein Begriff. Nicht nur wurde dort eine äußerst umfangreiche Grammatik angeboten, auch Flexionstabellen, deutsche Wörterbücher, die deutsche Wortgrammatik und ein Nachschlagewerk zur deutschen Rechtschreibung standen dort zur Verfügung.
>
> […]
>
> Da sich die IMTF-Gruppe verstärkt auf andere Gebiete konzentriert, wir aber die Informationen als hervorragende Ergänzung zu unserem eigenen Angebot ansehen, haben wir uns entschlossen, Teile von CanooNet.eu zu übernehmen um sie zu erhalten. Dies beinhaltet insbesondere die Deutsche Grammatik und den Blog "Fragen Sie Dr. Bopp!". Die anderen Bestandteile von CanooNet.eu sind zum Teil bereits in unserem Angebot vorhanden (z. B. die deutschen Flexionstabellen), zum Teil lassen sich diese nicht einfach in unser Angebot überführen oder werden von der IMTF-Gruppe für andere Projekte noch weiter genutzt.

Damit sind zumindest einige Links wieder tot.

Beispiele für funktionierende Umleitung:

- http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Artikelwort.html

Beispiel für tote Links:

- http://canoonet.eu/inflection/alt:A
- http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Scheinpartizip&language=0&project=1

Comment: [Question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71529). It seems the answer is *no*.

Comment: Au man. Ich habe LEO nie gemocht, allein schon, weil die Flexionstabellen teilweise Fehler enthalten und diese Verwirrung hier mindestens zweimal unnötige Fragen produziert hat. Und nun überführt man eine funktionierende, professionelle, designtechnisch einwandfreie Referenz-Plattform (canoo.net) in diese unübersichtliche, überfrachtete, schlecht designte Sprachlern-Plattform (LEO). Damit hat es sich dann wohl als ehemals gute Referenz.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<sup>(English translation below)</sup>

Die neue Situation ist für mein Skript wahrscheinlich zu schwierig zu lösen. Um Ihnen eine Idee zu geben, der letzte in der Frage erwähnte Link:

1. http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Scheinpartizip&language=0&project=1

wurde ursprünglich hier gehostet:

2. http://canoo.net/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Scheinpartizip&language=0&project=1

Diese Seite wurde in der Wayback Machine archiviert:

3. https://web.archive.org/web/20150510021624/http://canoo.net/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Scheinpartizip&language=0&project=1

und *einige* (aber nicht alle) Inhalte wurden verschoben nach:

4. https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wortbildungsregeln/Derivation/To-A/N-To-A/Pseudopart.html

Mein Skript *kann* den Wayback Machine-Link (3.) finden, aber nur, wenn die URL genau übereinstimmt (einschließlich der Parameter `language` und `project`) *und* es muss wissen, dass [diese](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Scheinpartizip&language=0&project=1) und [diese](https://dict.leo.org/pages/about/ende/canoonet_de.html) Seiten nutzlos sind; es könnte noch viel mehr geben.

---

<sup>(English translation)</sup>

The new situation is probably too difficult to handle for my script. To give you an idea, the last link mentioned in the question:

1. http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Scheinpartizip&language=0&project=1

was originally hosted at

2. http://canoo.net/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Scheinpartizip&language=0&project=1

This page has been archived in the Wayback Machine:

3. https://web.archive.org/web/20150510021624/http://canoo.net/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Scheinpartizip&language=0&project=1

and *some* (but not all) content has been moved to:

4. https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wortbildungsregeln/Derivation/To-A/N-To-A/Pseudopart.html

My script *can* find the Wayback Machine link (3.) but only if the URL matches exactly (including those `language` and `project` parameters) *and* it needs to know that [this page](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Scheinpartizip&language=0&project=1) and [this page](https://dict.leo.org/pages/about/ende/canoonet_de.html) are useless; there might be a lot more.

---

**Aktualisierung:** das Script is jetzt Fertig, und [nur zwei Beiträge](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Acanoo.net) verlinken noch auf die alte Website. Einer ist gesperrt und kann nicht bearbeitet werden; der andere enthält einige Links, die auf der neuen Website nicht vorhanden sind. Die geänderten Beiträge werden am besten in [meinem Profil] [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/15821/glorfindel?tab=activity) überprüft, schauen Sie bitte die Änderungen vom 19.08.2019 bis 19.02.2020 an.

**Update:** the script has finished now, leaving [only two posts](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Acanoo.net) still linking to the old website. One of them is locked and I can't edit them; the other one contains some links which don't exist on the new website. The changed posts are best checked on [my profile](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/15821/glorfindel?tab=activity), looking at the edits from 2019-08-19 to 2020-02-19.

---

<sup>(English translation below)</sup>

Es handelt sich hier um [520 Fragen und Antworten](http://web.archive.org/web/20190822091601/https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Acanoo.net) – sehr viel Arbeit, auch wenn wir das über verschiedene Freiwillige verteilen. Ein anderes Problem ist, dass, wenn wir diese Links aktualisieren, alte Fragen wieder auf der [Startseite](https://german.stackexchange.com/) sichtbar sind – das heißt, neue Frage bekommen dann keine Beachtung mehr.

Ich habe ein Programm, ['Broken Image Repairer'](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f), das mit ein Paar kleinen Anpassungen diese Links automatisch reparieren kann. Es ist möglich diese Bearbeitungen zu begrenzen, z.B. dass das Programm nur drei Fragen oder Antworten pro Tag verbessert. Es ist auch möglich, nur Posts mit einer Bewertung von mindestens +1 (oder eine andere Zahl) zu bearbeiten, und geschlossene Fragen zu überspringen.

Bitte lass mich wissen, ob das gewünscht ist. Das Programm bearbeitet mit meinem Benutzerkonto, und meine Reputation reicht, um die Review Queue nicht explodieren zu lassen.

---

<sup>(English translation)</sup>

This pertains to [520 questions and answers](http://web.archive.org/web/20190822091601/https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Acanoo.net) – a lot of work, even when we split it among several volunteers. Another problem is that when we update these links, old question will be visible again on the [homepage](https://german.stackexchange.com/) – that means, new questions will get less or no attention anymore.

I have a program, ['Broken Image Repairer'](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f), which after a few small adjustments can automatically repair these links. It's possible to rate limit these edits, for example that the program only edits three questions or answers per day. It is also possible to only edit posts with a score of +1 or higher (or another number), and skip closed questions.

Please let me know if this is desired. The program edits with my user account and my reputation suffices to not have the review queue explode.

Comment: Die deutsche Sprache ist nicht meine Muttersprache, bitte korrigieren Sie meine Fehler. Oder wenn etwas unklar is, bitte lass mich wissen.

Comment: Mit der Begrenzung auf ein paar Themen pro Tag erschiene mir das sehr sinnvoll. Mal sehen, was andere sagen.

Comment: 9 upvotes, 0 downvotes – darf man das als Akzeptanz deuten?

Comment: Sieht gut aus; aber nur hochstens 62 Benützer haben dieses Thema gesehen. Vielleicht kann einer der Moderatoren eine Bestätigung geben? Allerdings haben wir keine Eile.

Comment: @Glorfindel: auf German Language Meta sind +9/-0 schon eine ganz ordentliche Zustimmung, wir haben meist keine sehr große Metabeteiligung. Ich setze die Frage mal auf "featured", vielleicht kommen dann noch ein paar Votes dazu.

Comment: Herzlichen Dank – ich hätte erwartet das dieses Thema schon ein 'automatisches' "Hot Meta Post" war auf Grund der Wertungen.

Comment: I haven't checked individual posts on this. But this is a prime example of link rot. And *the need for quotes!* Can this script check for surroundings, that is link plus quote? Granted that this is not always necessary, in quite few it will be:

Comment: The Broken Image Repairer had some code to check if an image is used in a linked page; that was rather prone to false positives. The main problem is that not everybody uses blockquotes (`>`), and the quoted page may be updated causing difference between the quote in the post and the source. I agree completely with you that the relevant part of the source should be in the answer, the link is only for attribution + optionally a 'read more here if you're interested in the topic'.

Comment: Fantastisch! Und jetzt hoffen wir, daß canoo nicht nochmal umzieht...

Answer (score 3):

Danke für den Hinweis. Es ist sehr ärgerlich, wenn Seiten, auf die wir hier gerne verweisen, ihre Domain umziehen. Dagegen können wir nichts tun, aber es ist der Hauptgrund, weshalb wir erwarten, dass immer auch der Inhalt einer verlinkten Seite wiedergegeben wird.

> Wir alle sollten mit einem Edit alle nicht mehr gültigen Links aus Beiträgen löschen, bzw. durch die aktuellen Links ersetzen. Ist dieser nicht bekannt, sollten wir in einem Kommentar darauf hinweisen.

Bei Canoo kann man einfach den Domain Namen austauschen, die Struktur der Seite hat sich ansonsten offenbar nicht geändert.

```
http://canoo.net/  ==> http://www.canoonet.eu/
```

Ich habe das für meine Antworten gemacht, wenn sie mehr als 5 Upvotes hatten, damit nicht die erste Seite mit meinen alten Beiträgen zugemüllt wird. Letztlich sollten wir aber alle ungültigen Links entfernen.

Jeder darf da gerne mithelfen. Benutzer, die weniger als 1000 Reputatiospunkte haben, erhalten sogar +2 Punkte für jeden akzeptieren Edit.

---

Thank you for spotting this. It is indeed a major issue when pages we often link to had moved their domain. Nothing we can do about this but it is the main reason why we require to not only post a link but also at least some content we had found there.

> All of us should edit a post to remove a broken link and add the correct one. If the correct link is unknown we should comment on the post to point to this issue.

For canoonet it would be easy because we will only have to change the top domain name as the remainder of the site apparently was unchanged:

```
http://canoo.net/  ==> http://www.canoonet.eu/
```

I did that for my answers with more than 5 upvotes to avoid cluttering the main page with ancient answers of mine but in the end we should edit all broken links.

Everybody is welcome to do so, and people with less than 1000 reputation get +2 rep for every suggested edit that was accepted in the review queue.